# How to say, "You call this toy an 'X'?"

Tags: english-to-japanese, casual

(I hope to *never* be this rude to someone by saying such a phrase.)

Context: I would like to use it as a caption for a piece of art for a game, where a character unlocks a type of weapon after a certain level. Insulted, he says, `You call this toy an "X" weapon?` The character thinks it's a toy due to how it looks, and is in disbelief as to why people call it `X`. (The `X` is a proper noun, usually written as katakana. The character has a strong skill with the same name, hence his confusion.)

It has the same tone as, `You call that a date? (We just ate at McDonald's.)` or `You call this an essay? (It's hardly five sentences!)`

From what I know, I would phrase it as, `こんなおもちゃなんて、「X」というのか？`

Is it natural? Does it mean what I think it means? Is there another way to express this type of sentence better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

だと言うのか can be contracted to だってのか

These are some of the ways I would say it:

> あれがXだってのか？
>
> あれをXと呼ぶのか？
>
> Xだと？
>
> Xだというのか？
>
> こんなおもちゃなんて、Xと呼ぶつもり？
>
> これがX(か)？